# Switching the layout in the oncreate method with setContentView. Is this possible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to switch the content of an activity using the setContentView in a similar manner:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (condition) {

  setContentView(R.layout.layout1);

} else {

  setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
}

...
}
```

In the folders:
   layout1.xml
   layout2.xml

It works but if after setConentView I want to reference a control in the layout2..like a TextView, using FindViewById ..I get an error and the program crashes.
What's the problem. ?

Comment: can you give a little more source code.  Where you reference the control in the activity and also the code for the xml for the layout?

Comment: There's many code..It will be not relevant..but essentially the two xml files are the same ..except that the second xml contains the same controls of the first xml with the same Id's + other IDs.

Comment: Try referencing your TextView only in the condition you need it to be in. Also, if you provide the error, that would help quite a bit.

Comment: Application has stooped unexpectedly. Please try again. It's like findViewById doesn't find the controls in the layout and crashes. The same problem on all the controls .

Comment: Claudio, you need to post the exact crash logs from Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference a `View` from one of your layouts in an `Activity`, you need to:

1. Make sure that it exists in the given layout
2. Make sure that the given layout is set using the `setContentView()` method.